# processor with the condition SpringBatch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a structure in Spring Batch. 1. xmlItemReader reads xml, it has a date. Date one. 2. Then there is a processor that should by condition `if (one <current)` create a list of dates smaller than today's. 3. Then write this list to the txt file.

1 is implemented as

```
@Bean
    public ItemReader<Bic> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Bic> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Bic>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.xml"));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Bic>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                setNames(new String[]{"date"});
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Bic>() {{
                setTargetType(Bic.class);
            }});
        }});
        return reader;
    }
```

3 is implemented as

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter itemWriter() {
        return  new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Foo>()
                                   .name("itemWriter")
                                   .resource(new FileSystemResource("target/test/output.txt"))
                                   .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
                                   .build();
}
```

How to implement the processor with the condition in step 2?

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean by "create a list of dates". Can you describe what is the input and output of your processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your classes structure the way to go can be the following:

1. Create new class e.g. **MyProcessor.java** PSEUDO CODE IS FOLLOWING

   ```
   public class MyProcessor implements ItemProcessor<InputData, OutputData>{
   @Override
       public OutputData process(InputData item) throws Exception {

       if(item.checkingDate.isBefore(LocalDAteTime.now()){
            log.info("Skipping {}", item);
            return null;
       }

    //do your stuff
       return new OutputData();
   }
   ```

Add your processor to your job config e.g.:

```
@Bean
Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .listener(dataProcessor)
            .<InputData, OutputData>chunk(100)
            .faultTolerant()
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(new MyProcessor())
            .writer(itemWriter())
            .build();
}
```